# Insert null value into sql table row using sql data adapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, null

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"mycon_string"); 

SqlDataAdapter tabela_studenti_data = new SqlDataAdapter();

tabela_studenti_data.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into tabela_studenti VALUES(@Fist_name,@Last_Name,@Notification_ID)",connection);

 tabela_studenti_data.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@First_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_emri.Text;

tabela_studenti_data.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Last_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_mbiemri.Text;


**tabela_studenti_data.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Notification_ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = null;**
```

When I equal the last code with null, the code doesn't work. If I equal with a random number it works. I need it null for now, but It doesn't seem to go this way, any ideas ?

Comment: What is your table structure? Why did you not specify the columns in the insert statement? It is always a bad idea to insert without specifying the column names.

Comment: Try [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did you try `DBNull` yet?

Comment: Mark C. DBNull worked , Thank a lot mate :)

Comment: So instead of null its DBNull.Value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    tabela_studenti_data.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Notification_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value=DBNull.Value;
```